# Using kotlin expression annotations

Tags: kotlin, annotations

Kotlin allows to annotate expressions. It is however unclear, how such annotations may be useful and how to use them.

Let's say in following example I would like to check, that string contains number specified in @MyExpr annotation. Can this be achieved and how?

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.EXPRESSION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class MyExpr(val i: Int) {}

fun someFn() {
    val a = @MyExpr(1) "value#1";
    val b = @MyExpr(2) "value#2";
}
```

Comment: This would only be useful at compile time. I think this could be achieved with kapt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying `@Target(AnnotationTarget.EXPRESSION)` is just a way of telling the compiler where the user of the annotation can put it.

It does not do anything on it's own rather than that.

So e.g.

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.EXPRESSION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class Something


// compiler will fail here:
@Something class Foo {

    // but will succeed here:
    val a = @Something "value#1"
}
```

---

**Unless you're writing an Annotation Processor (so a thing that looks for Annotations and does something with them), your annotations have just informational value.** They are just a signal to other devs (or future You) of something.

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.EXPRESSION)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class UglyAndOldCode

val a = @UglyAndOldCode "this is something old and requires refactoring"
```

---

If you want to implement what you've stated in your question you would have to create an Annotation Processor that checks expressions marked with `MyExpr` for the condition that you've specified.